# How would i display what data is being sent?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Using Jquery ajax post how would i show a message with what data is about to be posted.

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function (request) {
    //something here
  },
  type: "POST",
  url: "delete/process.php",
  data: "delcustomerid="+ delcustomerid,
  success: refreshTable
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ 
  beforeSend: function (request) { 
    alert("delcustomerid="+ delcustomerid);
  }, 
  type: "POST", 
  url: "delete/process.php", 
  data: "delcustomerid="+ delcustomerid, 
  success: refreshTable 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and `console.log(request)`